# Base64 encoded image data sent from C# to PHP yields broken displayed image

Tags: c#, php, image, encoding, base64

Yesterday I asked a question and implemented an answer concerning how to send image data from a C# application to a PHP web page ready to receive the POST data, decode it, and display the image.

Here's the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApplication1

{



 class Program
{       

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Load a image
        System.Drawing.Image myImage = GetImage("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg");

        // Convert to base64 encoded string
        string base64Image = ImageToBase64(myImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // Post image to upload handler
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues("www.myurl.com", new NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "myImageData", base64Image }
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Server Said: " + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static System.Drawing.Image GetImage(string filePath)
    {
        WebClient l_WebClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] l_imageBytes = l_WebClient.DownloadData(filePath);
        MemoryStream l_stream = new MemoryStream(l_imageBytes);
        return Image.FromStream(l_stream);
    }

    static string ImageToBase64(System.Drawing.Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here's the PHP code:

```
   <?php 

// Handle Post
if (count($_POST))
{
    // Save image to file
    $imageData = base64_decode($_POST['myImageData']);

    // Write Image to file
    $h = fopen('test.jpg', 'w');
    fwrite($h, $imageData);
    fclose($h);

    // Success
    exit('Image successfully uploaded.');
}

// Display Image
if (file_exists('test.jpg'))
{
    echo '<img src="test.jpg?_='. filemtime('test.jpg') .'" />';
}
else
{
    echo "Image not uploaded yet.";
}

?>
```

Everything seems to work up to a certain point--I get a console message that says the image was successfully uploaded, but when I visit my webpage, I get a broken image, rather than stating the "Image not uploaded yet".  From this I think I can conclude everything is at least working enough to send the data from C# to PHP--it just seems like the encoding/decoding of the image itself is not working properly.  Oddly, earlier on in this project, we were doing something similar with encoding and decoding images, but the python code only works in linux--not windows.  Linux would give the right image, windows only displayed a broken image with the same code.

Any ideas on what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: As a way to debug, save the base64 string in your client and your server before decoding it and compare them to ensure the received data is the same and no scaping is done on it. If it is exactly equal then you can think it really is the base64 decoding (but I doubt, I use it myself with PHP and never had troubles).

Comment: check the size of the file after it's written, confirm that it's the same as what was uploaded. check md5 hashes to see if anything got changed, etc... by itself the code you've posted shouldn't do anything to the image except spit it out to the disk. so check if the inputs are ok.

Comment: So, for example, to test the PHP POST, just do something like echo print_r($_POST); to check?  That gives "Array() 1".

Comment: Okay, so, when I print out the contents of the base64 encoded string in C#, I get an extremely long string, as expected.  But when I do "echo print_r($_POST); to get the information that's sent to the webpage, it just returns "Array() 1" and nothing else.  Unless I'm not requesting the same sort of information, it seems like the two values are unequal.  Fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose a different (smaller) image like http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Banteay_Kdei%2C_Angkor%2C_Camboya%2C_2013-08-16%2C_DD_15.JPG/640px-Banteay_Kdei%2C_Angkor%2C_Camboya%2C_2013-08-16%2C_DD_15.JPG it's working perfectly.

So I'm afraid you're reaching the upload limit for post data, which should be 8MB in PHP by default. The image you're trying to upload is 12MB and Base64 encoded it is close to 20MB.

`post_max_size` in the `php.ini` can be modified to increase the post limit. But I highly recommend switching to regular file upload. See WebClient.uploadFile ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: I was thinking the image might be too big for POST as well (it was just a test image), but I also just tried the code with the image you linked, and it's still making a broken image on the webpage.  We're also using Wordpress...not sure if that could have anything to do with it.

Comment: Maybe the POST limit is even smaller in your case. Wordpress should not affect the code, if it is a single file without any wordpress bootstrapping - which were the circumstances I tested it with.

Comment: Any suggestions on where else to potentially test the code?  It seems to throw a fit when I try to use XAMPP and a local Apache server as the myImage = GetImage target.

Comment: XAMPP with a local Apache is working for me. Have you tried file upload? I possibly yield less problems considering is is intended to receive more content.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work on the XAMP site, so that's good progress!  So I know the code is valid.  It's just our servers...hmm.  I'll play around with the PHP settings a bit, and also try out the WebClient.fileUpload method as well.  Any tips on how that method might work most efficiently?  Thanks!